# power point is turned off but usb charger led still flicks on

Tags: electrical, 240v

I have a 240v power point, the switch is turn off but a usb charger i have plugged in flashes about once every two minutes.
Why would it flash if the power switch is off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a tiny amount of leakage into the charger due to capacitive coupling between parallel wires, just enough for a *very* efficient power supply to charge up and occasionally flash.

To prove the point, put the charger in a double socket (or power strip) with a small *incandescent* lamp plugged in next to it. If the power supply no longer flashes when the outlet is turned off, it shows that there's no problem - just highly efficient electronics.

Another possibility is that the USB charger has an internal battery, i.e., it is also meant to be power bank, and the flash is a warning it's being discharged.

Answer (score -1):

possibly the outlet is miss-wired and the switch is operating on the neutral and then the charger is capacitively coupling the live voltage (which can't be turned off) to the universe to complete the circuit.

Having the switch on a switch loop would be another possibility. switch loops capacitivlely leak a small amount of current past the switch.